# Is it mandatory for all nodes of cassandra cluster to have same cluster name?

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise, cassandra-2.1

Cassandra version 2.1.8

Is it mandatory for all nodes of cassandra cluster to have same cluster name ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer is `YES`. Otherwise, you'll get the following error.

Example ERROR for different *cluster_name*:

```
ERROR [main] 2014-02-25 01:51:17,377 CassandraDaemon.java (line 237) Fatal exception during initialization
org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ConfigurationException: Saved cluster name Test Cluster != configured name thisisstupid
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.SystemKeyspace.checkHealth(SystemKeyspace.java:542)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:233)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:462)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:552)
```

It is mandatory to have the same *cluster_name* for every single node in a cluster.

Answer (score 0):

All nodes in the same cluster should have same cluster name. It's madatory.